# FileSystemWatcher.Changed event gets triggered when shared excel file is closed

Tags: vb.net, filesystemwatcher

I'm using the FileSystemWatcher.Changed event in my VB.NET application to track changes in files, mainly Excel files. I have used NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or NotifyFilters.Attributes.

I have observed that the Changed event gets triggered when shared Excel files are closed, which does not happen in the case of non-shared Excel files.

I wanted to know if there is any specific reason behind this behavior and if there is a way to check if the Changed event got triggered because of closing the file. I have checked other forums and did not find any relevant cases and solutions.
Also, I wanted to know if there is a way to trigger the Changed event only when changes are made to the Excel files or when the Excel files are saved.

```vb
' Sample code:
Sub New()
    Dim watcher As New FileSystemWatcher
    watcher.Path = "E:\FSW"
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or NotifyFilters.Attributes
    watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf File_Changed
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub
Private Sub File_Changed(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine($"Changed event occured Name: {e.Name}, FullPath:{e.FullPath}, ChangeType:{e.ChangeType}")
End Sub
```

Comment: What sort of application-level issues are caused by this? Cannot you solve this by changing design at a higher level? I don't know why or what Excel does but the reality is that various editors can change various files at various times and you won't be able to asses the magnitude/relevance of those changes without understandong their formats. That being said, I think you could just compare the file before/after and see what changed. There's also tools like filemon or procmon that can help here.

Comment: When you open a shared file, you can see who else has it open. I would assume the file itself must be changed in order to indicate who has it open, so opening and closing a shared file would require a change. I don't see any way around a `FileSystemWatcher` raising a `Changed` event for such a change. If you want to exclude such a change from your logging then I would think that it would be up to you analyse the file at the time to confirm that it is indeed a content change. You'd need to do your own research on what changes in that case to determine what to exclude.